# NullPointerException on ContainsKey on TreeMap vs no exception on HashMap

Tags: java

So I was doing some coding using Maps recently and I stumbled on a `NullPointerException` in this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(1,1);
map.containsKey(null);
```

This threw a standard `NullPointerException`.
However since this was for a hand in and I knew that other people did not get this exception on the hand in that something was going weird so I tested this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1,1);
map.containsKey(null);
```

This did not throw the exception.

And basically I was wondering why this behavior was occuring, since optimally behavior between `hashmap` and `treemap` should be identical apart from the time to do certain functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [`Map.containsKey(Object key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)), you find the description of the exception:

> NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map does not permit null keys (optional)

So it is up to the implementation to decide to throw it or not (throw in the term define the throws in the declaration too)

You see that in the [`HashMap.containsKey(Object key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) it is not define as expected by your code.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on AxelH's an Murat's answer: lets look to source code

**TreeMap**

```
public V get(Object key) {
    Entry<K,V> p = getEntry(key);
    return (p==null ? null : p.value);
}

final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
    if (comparator != null)
        return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
    if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    ...
}
```

As you see, it throws a `NPE` if `key == null`

**HashMap**

```
transient Entry[] table;

public V get(Object key) {
    if (key == null)
        return getForNullKey();
    ...
}

private V getForNullKey() {
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.key == null)
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As for `HashMap`, `get()` checks if there's an `Entry` with key `null`, and returns the value of that `Entry`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the implementation is different.

TreeMap Throws: [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object))

- ClassCastException - if the specified key cannot be compared with the
  keys currently in the map
- NullPointerException - if the specified key
  is null and this map uses natural ordering, or its comparator does
  not permit null keys

HashMap does not throw and returns boolean. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object))